# Electron kill process by process name on windows, mac(darwin) and linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-forge

**How can I kill processes by process names in Windows, Darwin, and Linux**?
Like, assume the process I need to kill is 'vlc.exe' (basically close the application).

Here is the function I wrote to check whether this process is running or not.

```
const isRunning = (query, cb) => {
    let platform = process.platform;
    let cmd = '';
    switch (platform) {
        case 'win32': cmd = `tasklist`; break;
        case 'darwin': cmd = `ps -ax | grep ${query}`; break;
        case 'linux': cmd = `ps -A`; break;
        default: break;
    }
    exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        stdout = stdout.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '');

        cb({status: stdout.indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1});
    });
}
```

I call this function as

```
isRunning('vlc.exe', (vlc) => {
    console.log({ vlc }); // true|false
});
```

So, I know that VLC is running or not. Now I want to close it if it`s running.
For windows its **taskkill** but for darwin and Linux? Or is there any other way to kill processes?

Comment: `kill` following by pid for both platform should do the job

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? Also, I know that vlc.exe is running then how will I know the PID of the process?

Answer (score 1):

The PID is in the `ps` output. If `pidof` is available you could do `kill $(pidof vlc)`. Rather than write your own code to figure out PIDs and do the killing, you could also use [a well-tested module](https://github.com/sindresorhus/fkill) for the same purpose.

Comment: This module 'fkill' that you provided works well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On macOS and most probably on linux as well. process name is `VLC`. System are case sensitive so looking for `vlc.exe` or `vlc` will not find any running process.

you can play around by doing something like

```
kill $(ps aux | grep -i 'vlc' | awk '{print $2}')
```

which will

- `ps aux` - look for all process
- `grep -i 'vlc'` filter ps out by capturing process with name `VLC` or `vlc` (think the -i parameter which force the case insensitive).
- `awk '{print $2}'` only capture the PID number.
- `kill` ask the system to graceful stop the process by given PID.